# center align inline-block set to position relative

Tags: html, css, sass

**If you go to http://checkify.ca/science-world/**

I am trying to centre the three circles that flip over when hovered. Currently I have

CSS

```
.flip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 295px;
    min-height: 380px;

    @include perspective(1000);
    .flip-front, .flip-back {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        @include transform-style(preserve-3d);
        @include backface-visibility(hidden);
        @include transition(0.75s);
    }
    .flip-front {
        z-index: 5;
    }
    .flip-back {
        z-index: 0;
        @include rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    &:hover .flip-front {
        z-index: 5;
        @include rotateY(180deg);
    }
    &:hover .flip-back {
        z-index: 10;
        @include rotateY(0deg);
    }
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. The parent element "Intro" also is set to text-align: center; but this has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're absolutely positioning them and you have a set width, you can just add this to the .flip-front .flip-back:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -115px;
```

Additionally, you could just get rid of the .flip wrapper and do this:

```
#intro .circle{
    margin: 60px 47.75px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They already look pretty close to center, just shifted a bit too far to the left. I was able to center them by setting .flip's width to 230px (the width of the circle), setting float:left for the left hand circle, and setting the right hand circle to float:right. The center circle didn't need anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely positioning the `.flip-front` and `.flip-back` elements, and then fixing them to the left with `left: 0;`.

You can force these elements to take up all the width they are given by adding:

```
right: 0;
```

This will stretch the circles, but there are a few ways to fix that. For example, you could set their width to a fixed value with:

```
width: 230px;
```